# Git merge leads to changed source branch

Tags: git

I have a question regarding git. In the picture you can see a graph of my project git commit history. My feature branch (the blue line on the left side) and the master branch (the red on the right side).

[image: Picture of Git History Graph]

As you can see I worked some time on my feature and later decided to merge into master. That is displayed by the arrow that points to the red master branch.

Then I started working directly in the master and made some changes there which can also be seen in the picture.

The problem or the question is: When I wanted to checkout my old feature branch that should have been at the state before the merge into master I realized that my feature branch "followed" the master and all commits I made in master were also in my feature branch. I don't get that. How can that happen or did I miss something?

I merged into master and that shouldn't to anything to my feature branch. So why do all commits that I made in the master branch afterwards affect my feature branch? Hope someone has any idea.

I'm from Germany so English is not my first language tried my best to explain the problem.

Comment: The image graph here is barely useful. Can you add the (text, not image) output of `git log --all --graph --decorate` or something alike?

Comment: hmm... ok than i have to live without an answer. its company related and i am not allowed to post graphs wth data etc her. was hoping you would see something or have an idea with just that information. I looked up the graph wth the comment you gave and to be honest it looked nearly the same. it just had the commit messages included. And at the point when i merged into master the message was "merged branch XXXX into master." Besides that i dont see what benefit you would have from seeing the messages etc?

Comment: We don't even know which branch is which... Anonymize all you want, we clearly don't need your private data.

Comment: i just want to know what you expect to see there ? it looks exactly the same?

Comment: Branch names. Not real ones if that's top secret. But branch names we can reason on. What do you expect *us* to do with an unannotated graph?

Comment: And i said the left branch in blue is the feature branch and the right branch in red is the master. there are just 1 blue and 1 red lines.... also i said blue line left and red line right. how can you not know wich one is wich when you have that info? You should be able to see the colors..

Comment: Well, my bad, I somehow missed it.

Comment: ok fine. and as you can see i merged into the master. The message was Merged branch XXX into master. So the content if my feature branch shoould now be included in the master branch but not the content of the master in my feature branch. so why does my feature branch now contain all commits from the master. as you cann see there there is no arrow from master that points back to my feature branch..

Comment: There's no reason the source branch would be affected in any way by the merge. Something else messed with your branch. Maybe try to inspect the branch's positions history through `git reflog <branch_name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is not really about branches or files: it's really about *commits*.  The dots on the lines represent the commits.  Each commit has a unique hash ID, and that hash ID gets you that commit.

Each commit *stores* two things:

- a full snapshot of every file, as of the form it had (in Git's index aka staging area) when you told Git to make that commit; and
- some metadata, including things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit.

The snapshot is stored with all the file contents *de-duplicated* (within and across commits), so the fact that we mostly re-use most files from commit to commit means that the files actually take very little space.  (They're further compressed, sometimes very much so, with tricky methods that we don't have to care about; just knowing that they're de-duplicated should make us comfortable with the idea of re-using files in each commit.)

The *metadata*, importantly, holds a list of *previous* commit hash IDs.  For most commits, this "list" is just one entry long.  It's what connects one dot in your graph to the previous dot.  For a few commits, the list has *two*—technically, some integer n ≥ 2, but unless you get fancy it's just two—entries, and then you get that little arrow as well as the line.  **That's just how your graph-drawing software *draws* the graph.**  The actual storage is a list of hash IDs in each commit's metadata, remembering the hash ID for some previous commit(s).

> The problem or the question is: When I wanted to checkout my old feature branch that should have been at the state before the merge into master I realized that my feature branch "followed" the master and all commits I made in master were also in my feature branch.

A *branch name*, in Git, is just a way Git gives us humans to work with commits where we (humans) don't have to memorize hash IDs.  When you say `git checkout old-feature-branch`, the *name* `old-feature-branch` is simply a *commit number*.  Git extracts the saved files from that commit.

When you use some *viewer* to *look at* commits, the graph it draws—if it draws one—is up to that viewer.  The commits are joined by the hash IDs stored in their metadata: there is nothing more and nothing less; that's all there is to join commits.  The *branch names* select one particular commit, and that's all they do.  We say that the commit selected *by* the branch name is the *tip commit* of that branch.

We can start with the tip commit and work backwards.  Since the hash IDs in the list in each commit are always hash IDs of *previous* commits,<sup>1</sup> we can *only* work backwards.  As we do work backwards, we find more commits.  We usually say that some or all of the commits that we can find by doing this are "on the branch", whatever that means.  But since multiple *names* can point to the *same commit*, and each *merge commit* points backwards to two or more previous commits, it's pretty likely that many commits are found by many names.

Indeed, the very first commit ever made, in some repository, is usually found by *every* branch name.  This first commit is a bit special: its list of previous commits is *empty*, because there was no previous commit.  It's where the action stops, and where history ends (or starts, if you like to think about time going forwards instead of backwards the way Git works).  That is, in a sort of branch-y repository, if commit `A` is the very first commit and later commits are placed to the right, we get:

```
       D   <-- br1
      /
     C--E   <-- br2
    /
A--B
    \
     F--G   <-- br4
      \
       H   <-- br5
```

and as you can see, commits `A` and `B` are on *every* branch.  Is there a name pointing to commit `B`?  Well, there isn't in this drawing, but let's add one now:

```
       D   <-- br1
      /
     C--E   <-- br2
    /
A--B   <-- br3
    \
     F--G   <-- br4
      \
       H   <-- br5
```

Commit `A` is still on every branch, but now that's five branches instead of four.  If we delete name `br4`, commit `G` becomes *un-find-able* unless you've saved its hash ID somewhere, and now commit `A` is only on four branches.

So the set of branches that contains any given commit changes dynamically.  The only surprise is that there's nothing surprising about this!

Comment: Hey. Many thx for that explanation. I definetly understand now better how the graph is created. But still i dont have a answer to my question... Imagine:  Branch f1 and master. F1 contains A->D->E And master A->B->C. Then i type checkout master and write git merge f1  leading to a mergecommit in my master branch. Masterbranch A->B->C->F(Mergecommit).   That makes sense. I decided to continue working in master and made some more commits A->B->C->F->G->H. Then after commiting i switched back to f1 and now all these commits were included there. How can that be? There should only be A->D->E

Comment: That kind of `git merge` makes a new merge commit, which adds to the current branch and links back to two (not just one) previous commits. The current branch name now points to the new commit. The other branch name doesn't move, so yes, if you `git checkout f1` and `f1` used to name commit `E`, it should still name commit `E`. Use `git rev-parse f1` to see the hash ID, or `git show f1` to see the commit found by the name; use `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name f1` to verify that `f1` is short for `refs/heads/f1` (i.e., is in fact a branch name).

Comment: If `f1` stores a different commit hash ID, some operation must have updated it. What operation? Well, that's where `git reflog` can come in handy: `git reflog f1` will show you the values that were stored in `f1` in the past (for at least a month or 90 days by default) and what operation stored each of those values.

Comment: Thx again for your answer. The branch is now deleted and i dont have time to investigate it even further. i am very greateful for your help and if that happens again i will investigate it in the way you described. I already marked you answer as helpful. Thank you m8